# Communication between REST endpoint instances

Tags: java, web-services, rest, session, jakarta-ee

A client connects to a JAX-RS Endpoint to retrieve data. This endpoint uses an EJB to access the database and perform logic then returns the data to the endpoint.

`Client <----> Rest Endpoint <----> EJB`

Before data can be returned to the Client, I need to pass data to another Endpoint instance (another Client that is connected to this Rest Endpoint). I would like to keep this a REST Service but I'm faced with two problems:

- **REST Endpoints are stateless.** So no Sessions are linked with an endpoint. However, this could be fixed with *context injection* (not as efficient) or passing a *userID* as a parameter.
- **No Communication method.** There's WebSockets but how would that help me communicate between Sessions on the server? There's JMS but from my understanding that works from application to application not Sessions.

**What I'm asking:** Is there a way to communicate between different REST (or EJB) instances/sessions? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to persist sessions to some external storage (like Redis) and pass the session identifier with each request between various system components. When such request is handled, you could load session state from the storage and proceed accordingly.

Most of the EJB/Servlet containers allow you to turn session persistence on.